# How to properly compare variable and a string in Bash?

Tags: bash

I am doing bash scripting for the first time and I decided to try to compare two strings and even though my syntax is alright as far as I know, it still doesn't work.

I read through a couple of older questions and they don't offer anything I haven't tried before

I tried the following:
Using ==; =, -eq

```
    echo 'Enter the letter: '
    read l
    if  ["$l"='y' -o "$l"='Y'];then echo 'Yes'
    elif  ["$l"='n' -o "$l"='N']; then echo 'No'
    else echo 'Try again dum dum'
    fi
```

It reads the input correctly but when it comes to comparing the two strings it outputs the following:
YesNo.sh: line 3: [n=y: command not found
YesNo.sh: line 4: [n=n: command not found
Try again dum dum

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash logical expression ( '[' and '[[' ) require the tokens to be separated with spaces

```
if  [ "$l" = 'y' -o "$l" = 'Y' ];then echo 'Yes'
elif  [ "$l" = 'n' -o "$l" = 'N' ]; then echo 'No'
else echo 'Try again dum dum'
fi
```

Comment: `-o` can introduce ambiguity and is obsolete. Use `[ ... ] || [ ... ]` instead.

Comment: Since you mention it, `[[` doesn't support `-o` at all.

Comment: As a general rule, spaces are important delimiters in shell syntax. Adding or removing them can completely change (or invalidate) a command. So when you copy an example, don't add or remove them and expect it to work right.